# Mark as dupe of a dupe, or dupe of the original?

Tags: discussion, closing

Sometimes when a question is marked as a dupe, the linked question is also a dupe, like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227219/i-lost-the-person-following-me-in-skyrim-and-its-starting-to-become-a-problem) has been marked as a dupe of [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226498/skyrim-my-follower-is-missing-lost), which is also a dupe.

Should we mark it as a dupe of the dupe, or a dupe of the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to mark it as a dupe of the original. That way, if the dupe marked to be closed gets deleted, the link still links to an active question.

This can sometimes be difficult, in my experience, as questions marked as a dupe do not always provide a link to the original question.

Considering this, my answer would be that listing a 'dupe of a dupe' would be sufficient if it is the best you can do.